# Notify-send scripted to several other ubuntu's distros

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh, notify-send

I start to wonder if it's possible to make a script to send notifications once to several other Ubuntus, i must say that not all the computers have the same Distro, having MATE XUbunutu LUbuntu and different versions.

It's reliable to do via ssh ?? I want to send this push notifications to one or two PC per office

I'll bring the first problem it occurred to me when tried in Ubuntu MATE 20.04

> administrador@secto27:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
>
> > administrador@secto27:~$ notify-send "Titulo" "Hola"
> >
> > > GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

Comment: To be on-topic, a question needs to be narrow and specific -- we don't allow open-ended questions here. If you're having a specific problem writing a replacement for one _specific_ distro, that specific problem is suitable for a single question's scope. If you have a different problem with each of five distros, that's five questions (each of which should only be asked once you've verified that it isn't duplicative of anything else in the knowledge base).

Comment: ...so the XUbuntu failure, for example, could be _one_ question. We'd want more details, though -- exactly what command did you try to use over ssh? Were you checking that command's stderr and its exit status? What _was_ its exit status? What _was_ written to its stderr? Etc.

Comment: Ok. sorry bout that. let me tell you the whole thing. right now we have a those distros on our computers. In a few months we'd like to migrate the entire fleet to MATE, so let's get on that one... I'll edit the post to make it good right after this comment.

Comment: Try auth as user, which should see your notification

Comment: Does your PAM configuration for sshd start a systemd user session? The error looks to me like it doesn't.